Does docker / gitlab have a method to to check for latest package updates?
New to docker and containers, coming from a developer background, I was wondering is there a method or way to run something that will check the projects dependencies to see if there are or what are the latest versions/tagged releases available.
Something similar to Node Package Manager (NPM) where it tells you a detail list of all updates available to the project.
I'm never in favor of blindly using latest.
The program I'm on I'm looking over dependencies and can see several builds using containers that are several years old e.g. v1.19.0 and newer versions available e.g. 2.8.3.
The projects are build with GitLab pipelines so the package references are within the .gitlab-ci.yml files.
Looking for a way to report on projects to list out dependencies where newer releases are available and we may want to investigate updating our dependencies and test the builds.

It will be incredibly language-dependent, depending on both what language(s) are used in the application and what build tool(s).  Docker doesn't and can't have anything built in.
